# unable to write [error 22] invalid mod or file name

Tags: python-2.7

the error is this:

```
    mini: mkrule www.google.com therule
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/t11/Dropbox/2.0/cmd2.0.py", line 88, in <module>
    MiniDownloader().cmdloop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cmd.py", line 142, in cmdloop
    stop = self.onecmd(line)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cmd.py", line 221, in onecmd
    return func(arg)
  File "C:/Users/t11/Dropbox/2.0/cmd2.0.py", line 75, in do_mkrule
    functions2.write(self.RulesDir+site, xpath)
  File "C:\Users\t11\Dropbox\2.0\functions2.py", line 12, in write
    with open(path_file, mod) as FileObject:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\t11\\Dropbox\\2.0\\Rules\\https://www.google.com'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i am using the cmd module
and this is the function:

```
def write(path_file, data, mod="w", writeover=False):
        """ gets file path + name and contents
        check if the name is taken and if not write it (return's True if successful and False if not) """
        if os.path.exists(path_file) and writeover is not True:
            return False
        else:
            with open(path_file, mod) as FileObject:
                FileObject.write(data)
                FileObject.flush()
                return True
```

and i called the function here:

```
def do_mkrule(self, s):
        s = s.split()
        if len(s) != 2:
            self.help_mkrule()
            return
        site = s[0]
        xpath = s[1]
        site = functions2.url_check(site)
        if xpath == "del":
            os.remove(self.RulesDir+site)
            print "file "+site+" removed"
        else:
            if site != False:
                functions2.write(self.RulesDir+site, xpath)
                print "rule for "+site+" created"
```

The intent of the function is to get file path, name and contents, check if the name is taken and if not write it.

It should return True if successful and False if unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\t11\\Dropbox\\2.0\\Rules\\https://www.google.com'
```

The filename you passed to the function is invalid. There are many characters that Windows will not accept in filenames, including colons (`:`) and forward slashes (`/`).

You could get rid of them (a good contender is to replace invalid characters with underscores) or find another way of encoding the site's name in the filename, such as by having an index that lists the names (e.g. a file named "sites.json" with mappings from site to filename).